# Newspaper3k returns None summary

Tags: python, null, summary, article

I have been using Newspaper3k to summarize and generate keywords from locally stored html articles. While I can successfully generate keywords but not the summary.
The summary returned is always null.

Below is the code I am using

```
html = '''<div class="col-lg-11">\n
    <div class="entry-content e-content">\n
        <div class="img-right caption" style="width:300px"> <img alt="Plusnet" width="300" height="200" data-src="//dwkujuq9vpuly.cloudfront.net/news/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/plusnet-192701.jpg" data-sizes="auto" class="lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==">
            <noscript><img src="//dwkujuq9vpuly.cloudfront.net/news/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/plusnet-192701.jpg" alt="Plusnet" width="300" height="200"></noscript> \n
            <p>Plusnet offers broadband and home phone deals</p>\n</div>\n
        <p><strong>The Advertising Standards Authority (ASA) has upheld a complaint against PlusNet, accusing it of using misleading adverts on buses.</strong></p>\n
        <p>The ASA ruled that the BT-owned broadband service provider had misled customers into believing that they could sign up to a broadband package for £6.49 a month.</p>\n
        <p>The reality, the ASA said, was that the advertised package would cost some potential customers £12.99 a month, if they lived outside PlusNet’s low-cost area.</p>\n
        <p>It went onto add that even though PlusNet warned that the headlined price was not available to everyone, it did so in small type face on the bus advertisements, which were hard to read.</p>\n
        <p>Handing out its ruling the ASA said: ‘Small print should be clearly visible to a normally sighted person reading the marketing communication once from a reasonable distance and at a reasonable speed.</p>\n
        <p>‘We considered that the poster should have made clear that the quoted price of £6.49 for broadband was not available to all. Because the small print explaining that was illegible, we concluded that the poster was misleading.</p>\n
        <p>PlusNet was told to ensure that its smallprint on future ads were legible.</p>\n
        <h2>Which? responds</h2>\n
        <p>Ceri Stanaway, Which? broadband expert, said: ‘Its very frustrating to see a great broadband offer only to discover that you can’t get it because of where you live.</p>\n
        <p>‘Even though the PlusNet deal is available to 80% of UK households, PlusNet should have made the restrictions clearer for the 20% of households that can’t get it.</p>\n
        <p>She added: ‘Clearly, more work needs to be done by broadband providers, regulators and government to address the broadband digital divide.</p>\n
        <p><a href="/news/2011/01/cheaper-broadband-deals-for-rural-areas-242623/" title="">Cheaper broadband deals for rural areas</a></p>\n
        <p>To learn more about broadband, take a look at our Which? guide</p>\n
        <div>\n
            <h2>How to follow the latest Which? Tech news</h2>\n
            <p>Are you a <strong>Twitter</strong> user? Follow <a href="https://twitter.com/whichtech" title="" shape="rect">WhichTech on Twitter</a> for regular tech tweets.</p>\n
            <p>Prefer <strong>RSS</strong>? Don’t miss a thing with the <a href="https://www.which.co.uk/feeds/technology.xml" title="" shape="rect">Which? tech RSS feed</a>.\xa0</p>\n
            <p>For just the main headlines in <strong>newsletter</strong> form, sign-up to our weekly Which?\xa0tech email.</p>\n
            <p><a href="http://blogs.which.co.uk/technology/apple/apple-ipad-2-3g-data-plans-compared/" title="" shape="rect">Apple iPad 2 3G data plans compared</a> –\xa0find the best 3G plan for your iPad
                <br><a href="http://blogs.which.co.uk/technology/tablets-2/best-android-tablets-round-up/" title="" shape="rect">Best Android tablets round-up</a> – we look at the best iPad alternatives around
                <br><a href="https://www.which.co.uk/reviews/laptops/article/best-cheap-laptops-for-under-500" title="" shape="rect">Best cheap laptops for under £500</a> – find the best laptop deals</p>\n</div>\n </div>\n\n
    <footer class="entry-footer">\n\n \n
        <p class="entry-categories p-category">Categories:\xa0<a href="https://www.which.co.uk/news/uncategorised/" rel="category tag">Uncategorised</a></p>\n \n \n </footer>\n\n
    <div class="share share-mobile hidden-lg-up">\n <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.which.co.uk%2Fnews%2F2011%2F01%2Fasa-raps-plusnet-243477%2F" class="share__facebook" target="_blank" title="Share ASA raps PlusNet on Facebook" data-mobileurl="https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.which.co.uk%2Fnews%2F2011%2F01%2Fasa-raps-plusnet-243477%2F">\n\n    <span class="sr-only">Share on Facebook</span>\n  </a>\n\n <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.which.co.uk%2Fnews%2F2011%2F01%2Fasa-raps-plusnet-243477%2F&amp;text=ASA%20raps%20PlusNet" class="share__twitter" target="_blank" title="Share ASA raps PlusNet on Twitter" data-mobileurl="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.which.co.uk%2Fnews%2F2011%2F01%2Fasa-raps-plusnet-243477%2F&amp;text=ASA raps PlusNet">\n\n    <span class="sr-only">Share on Twitter</span>\n  </a>\n\n <a href="mailto:?subject=ASA%20raps%20PlusNet&amp;body=The%20Advertising%20Standards%20Authority%20(ASA)%20has%20upheld%20a%20complaint%20against%20PlusNet,%20accusing%20it%20of%20using%20misleading%20adverts%20on%20buses.%0D%0A%0D%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.which.co.uk%2Fnews%2F2011%2F01%2Fasa-raps-plusnet-243477%2F" title="Share ASA raps PlusNet by email" class="share__email">\n\n    <span class="sr-only">Share by email</span>\n  </a>\n</div>\n </div>
    </html>'''


article.set_html(html)
article.parse()
article.nlp()
article.keywords
article.summary
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you initiated nltk? nltk handles the summarization.

1. Add this line to top of your code:
   import nltk
2. Add this line before "article.nlp()" :
   nltk.download('punkt')#1 time download of the sentence tokenizer